# Embedding a 360 video into a website - mobile friendly

Tags: html, ios, video, 360-virtual-reality

Ok so I am planning to embed a 360 video into a website however need this video to play on ios through the native video player. I have looked into google vr view but when I tried to get it to work, I got a load error. Are there any other solutions that might work better?

This is what I tried when using google vr view.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300px" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/index.html?video=http://winn-brown.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Isle-of-Jaws-360-Video-2.mp4&is_stereo=true"></iframe>
```

Thanks